# Calculate average from JSON column

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, types, aggregate-functions

I have a table with a column of JSON data that I want to extract information from. Specifically I just want to get the average value.

Example of what I have:

```
id      speed_data
391982  [{"speed":1.3,"speed":1.3,"speed":1.4,"speed":1.5...
391983  [{"speed":0.9,"speed":0.8,"speed":0.8,"speed":1.0...
```

Example of what I want:

```
id      speed_data
391982  1.375
391982  0.875
```

Any suggestions on how to get this query to work?

```
select t.*, avg(x.speed)
from tbl t,
    json_array_elements(a->'speed') x
order by random()
limit 1
```

Comment: What result are you getting? Are your values being converted to ints?

Comment: You won't be able to do this. You have semantically invalid json: in a json object, every key must come up only once; this json is syntactically valid, but only the last pair (with key `"speed"`) will be seen in results (after parsing).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your json array is messed up, like [@posz commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27368219/calculate-average-from-json-column#comment43201338_27368219). Would have to be:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl (id int, speed_data json);

INSERT INTO tbl VALUES
  (391982, '{"speed":[1.3,1.3,1.4,1.5]}')
, (391983, '{"speed":[0.9,0.8,0.8,1.0]}');
```

You query is twisted in multiple ways, too. Would work like this in pg **9.3**:

```
SELECT t.id, avg(x::text::numeric) AS avg_speed
FROM   tbl t
     , json_array_elements(speed_data->'speed') x
GROUP  BY t.id;
```

[**SQL Fiddle.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/723de/9)

In the upcoming pg **9.4** we can simplify with the new `json_array_elements_text()` ( also less error-prone in the cast):

```
SELECT t.id, avg(x::numeric) AS avg_speed
FROM   tbl t
     , json_array_elements_text(speed_data->'speed') x
GROUP  BY t.id;
```

More Details:

- [How to turn json array into postgres array?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/54289/3684)

Aside: It would be much more efficient to store this as plain array (`numeric[]`, not `json`) or in a normalized schema to begin with.