# Finding multiple column average of the average of values in SQL json column

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, laravel, eloquent

Say I have a database with data in the following format

---

```
| id | name        | rating                                      |
-----------------------------------------------------------------|
| 1  | first       | {"looks": 20, "quality": 20, "quantity": 20}|
-----------------------------------------------------------------|
| 2  | second      | {"looks": 30, "quality": 40, "quantity": 20}|
------------------------------------------------------------------
```

First, I need to get the average of the rating of each item in the json object. For example, get average of `looks`, `quality` and `quantity`, for both item `first` and `second`. Item one would have an average rating of 20,
and item `second` would have an average rating of 30. Then get the average of the average ratings of the two items, that would be of `20` and `30`, which would give me a final result of 25.

I would like to implement this using the Laravel, Eloquent query builder, but I wouldn't mind getting this in raw sql format. I am using Postgres database.

I have found  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27379419/5393142) answer but it only adresses json with single key and not in multiple rows. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you know all the keys in the JSON column?

Comment: Yes I know all the keys. They are  the same for all rows.

Comment: you should try make it in separate column to make such type of calculations

Comment: I agree...however this is already on a live system in production.

Comment: Although you got the answer but it would be too slow for 100's or 1000's of row.

Answer (score 1):

You could use collections:

```
$collection = Model::get();
$ratings = $collection->map(function($i) {
    return collect(json_decode($i->rating))->avg();
});
```

And you want to add an average rating to result:

```
$collection = Model::get();
$collection->transform(function($i) {
    $i->average = collect(json_decode($i->rating))->avg();
    return $i;
});
```

Comment: Is it possible to have this solution in a query builder? where I could filter results before calling the get method?